# Javascript function in header showing as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, function, centering

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function centerItem(id,size)
{
    var pad = (window.innerWidth - size)/2;
    document.getElementById(id).style.marginLeft = pad+"px";
    document.getElementById(id).style.marginRight = pad+"px";
}

function login()
{
    document.getElementById('box').innerHTML="<img src="img/pleasewait.gif" />";
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('box').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://[lan ip]/Athena/lib/ajax/login.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("email="+email+"&pass="+pass);
}
</script>
```

That is in my `<head>` section, and I'm calling it using this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">centerItem('login',210);</script>
```

However, I'm getting an error saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: centerItem is not defined 
(anonymous function)"

Any thoughts?

Comment: Where is that `<script>` tag that calls the function located? In the `<head>` or in the `<body>`?

Comment: Also, you should call your funciton this way : `centerItem('login',210);`

Comment: You're missing a comma in your parameter list to `centerItem`.

Comment: The function is located in the <head> whereas the call is in the <body> right after the <div> with the id.

Comment: The missing comma was cause that second code part wasn't copy/pasted, but typed up in a hurry, it is like that in my original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById('box').innerHTML="<img src="img/pleasewait.gif" />";`
Should really be:
`document.getElementById('box').innerHTML="<img src=\"img/pleasewait.gif\" />"`

you need to escape the double quotes when creating the image tag.

And you should cache your selected elements.  The result would be something like:

```
function centerItem(id, size) {
    var pad = (window.innerWidth - size)/2,
        elem = document.getElementById(id);
    elem.style.marginLeft = pad+"px";
    elem.style.marginRight = pad+"px";
}

function login() {
    var xmlhttp;
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    box.innerHTML="<img src=\"img/pleasewait.gif\" />";

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            box.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://[lan ip]/Athena/lib/ajax/login.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("email="+email+"&pass="+pass);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, I just switched to wrapping it in single quotes and keeping it in double instead of escaping. It helps a newer person who is coming in behind me.